# What is the meaning of principal that has access to the machine's credentials?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, service-master-key

> The service master key can only be decrypted by the service account
> under which it was created or by a principal that has access to the
> machine's credentials.

What is the meaning of **...principal that has access to the machine's credentials**? A principal is an account. But what does it mean to have access to the machine's credentials?